# Parse Data from Apple Push Notification

Tags: json, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have push notifications being sent through Firebase, when a user does an action there is a php script sending pushes to the associated FCM tokens. The push notifications are being received, but I am trying to get the information from the "gcm.notification.payload" key. I have tried casting userInfo to a Dictionary, NSDictionary, [String:Any], JSON, and nothing is working. When I try and get say, payload["type"].string, the value is nil. Here is the closest I have gotten to being able to get something from inside the payload dictionary, where notification is the received UNNotification:

```
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo


let json = JSON(notification.request.content.userInfo)
guard let gcmNotificationPayload = json["gcm.notification.payload"].string else { return }
let payload = JSON(gcmNotificationPayload)
print("json \(json)")
print("payload \(payload)")
print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
```

Console Output:

```
  json {
      "gcm.message_id" : "0:1523811750249807%3990eb5d3990eb5d",
      "aps" : {
        "sound" : "default",
        "badge" : 1,
        "alert" : {
          "body" : "Tap to Open Herds List",
          "title" : "test4 test has added you to a herd!"
        }
      },
      "gcm.notification.payload" : "{\"image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/www.test.com\\\/images\\\/users\\\/417\\\/5acd085c97c3a.jpg\",\"type\":\"6\",\"title\":\"test4 test has added you to a herd!\",\"message\":\"Tap to Open Herds List\"}"
    }

    payload {"image":"https:\/\/www.test.com\/images\/users\/417\/5acd085c97c3a.jpg","type":"6","title":"test4 test has added you to a herd!","message":"Tap to Open Herds List"}

    [AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1523811750249807%3990eb5d3990eb5d, AnyHashable("aps"): {
        alert =     {
            body = "Tap to Open Herds List";
            title = "test4 test has added you to a herd!";
        };
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    }, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.payload"): {"image":"https:\/\/www.test.com\/images\/users\/417\/5acd085c97c3a.jpg","type":"6","title":"test4 test has added you to a herd!","message":"Tap to Open Herds List"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the let payload line to this solved the issue, and this was using SwiftyJSON for the record:

```
let payload = JSON.init(parseJSON: gcmNotificationPayload)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check out the [`Codable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) anyways, it makes handling `JSON` that much easier.